# New bloc pattern - How it works?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I am a beginner in Flutter and dart. I started learning bloc nowadays. When I get this code, I really didn't get it, how it works?

```
 CounterBloc() : super(0) {
    on<Increment>((event, emit) => emit(state + 1));
  }
```

1. Is they calling super constructor?
2. Defining it's constructor?
3. why on keyword used?
4. how second line works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things. First bloc is here to provide you with an abstract layer so it's not really important *why* it works but you should know *how* to use it.

However, here are answers to your questions:

1. The `super` constructor is used (`super(0)`) to set the initial state of your bloc
2. What you write is the definition of your bloc constructor yes, not sure what is the question here
3. `on` is **not** a keyword. It's a `method` of the `bloc` class. You can ctrl+click on it to see how it's defined but it is **not** a dart keyword.
4. The second line basically registers the given callback (in your case `(event, emit) => emit(state + 1)`) and maps it to an event type so that at a later date, when you use the event (`myBloc.add(Increment())`) bloc will call the given callback.

I hope its clearer. Don't hesitate to dive into the [bloc documentation](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/) as it is a precious resource (and is very pretty :D)

Comment: second question: is it defining counterbloc constructor or super class constructor?

Comment: "counterbloc constructor". A super class constructor cannot be changed from a subclass (this is true for every class in dart)

Comment: one more...about the second line.  here, if Increment event happened. it adds 1 to the state. isn't it? the given callback = here means the Increment ?

Comment: `Increment` is the *event* which causes the *callback* `(event, emit) => emit(state + 1)` to be called. The callback emits a new *state* (`state + 1`) so the state of the bloc will change after the event is added to the bloc (and the callback is triggered).

Comment: can we `emit` states outside `on` method?

Comment: You should not no. The idea is to always follow the "event -> bloc -> state -> ui" pattern